# makecform function is not applied to the following parameter : "whitepoint"

Tags: matlab

I want to use this matlab code to segment images 
but it gives me error to the following line :

```
cform = makecform('srgb2lab', 'whitepoint', whitepoint('d65'));
```

it gives me the following error :

**Error using ==> iptcheckstrs at 86**
 **Function MAKECFORM expected its second input argument,**
 **PROPERTYNAME,**
 **to match one of these strings:**

**AdaptedWhitePoint**

**The input, 'whitepoint', did not match any of the valid strings.**

I used AdaptedWhitePoint but it did not give me the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[makecform](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/makecform.html)

`C = makecform(type, 'WhitePoint', WP)` specifies the value of the reference white point. `type` can be either `'xyz2lab'` or `'lab2xyz'`. `WP` is a 1-by-3 vector of `XYZ` values scaled so that `Y = 1`. The default is `whitepoint('ICC')`. Use the `whitepoint` function to create the `WP` vector.

To use the 'srgb2lab' you have to make your name `'AdaptedWhitePoint'`

```
 C = makecform('srgb2lab', 'AdaptedWhitePoint', whitepoint('d65'))
```